# How do i change padding of my textview programmatically in my app widget?

Tags: android, android-layout

As `findviewbyid()` is not supported in widget i am unable to set TextView padding dynamically on widget.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no method. The appwidget is designed to not allow dynamic manipulating layout objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for API level > 16, you may use the following method to set a left padding for instance:

```
views.setViewPadding(R.id.widget_item_news_publishedDate_text, 20, 0, 0, 0);
```

Change the 20 to whatever dimension you need(you may even get a dimension from resource by calling

```
context.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.content_padding))
```

where content_padding  is say 8dp.

Does that help?